# Google Weather Parse XML

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

Trying to Parse XML using jQuery but I cannot get this working for the life of me.

```
var geoCity = "Aberdeen"
$.ajax({  
        type: "GET",  
        url: "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather="+geoCity,  
        dataType: "xml",  
        success: parseXml 
    });
    function parseXml(xml) {  
            $(xml).find("weather").each(function() {  
                $("body").append($(this).find("current_conditions").text() );  
                    });  
            }  
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

The tag current_conditions has no text. All of its children have attributes.

Also, your function should be:

```
function parseXml(xml) {  
        $(xml).find("weather").each(function() {  
            $("body").append($(this).find("current_conditions").text() );  
        });
    };
```